# How can I change Magento's default grid per page in my local.xml?

Tags: xml, layout, magento

New to magento here, I have figured out how to use my local.xml to do just about all the changes I need but the grid view has me stumped. I have changed my grid view to 5 columns, so the default 9 items displayed looks sloppy. I want to set it to a multiple of 5. Looking through catalog.xml I figured this should do it:

```
<reference name="product_list_toolbar_pager">
    <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>15</limit></action>
</reference>
```

within both category_catalog_default and category_catalog_layered handles, but no dice. I am struggling with Magento's scattered documentation, but actually coming to appreciate the whole layout thing.

I'm on 1.5.1, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Took me a long time to figure this one out. As it turns out, the pager values are set through the admin. System > configuration > catalog > catalog > frontend > "Products per Page on Grid Default Value"

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is answered, but I fond myself here.

You can use XML like this:

```
<reference name="product_list_toolbar">
  <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>30</limit></action>
</reference>
```

In either a `local.xml` file or in the Category `Custom Design` field.

What is worth noting though is that the **limit has to one of the values in the list** within System Config Catalog pages.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. At last I got my solution from u.. Actually I am directly copying th above code to custom layout update to Manage Categories of Admin.. It solves my problem..

Comment: You can actually add more limits to the pager without adding it to the list in the System Config by adding : `<action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>grid</mode><limit>30</limit><label>30</label></action>`

Answer (score 2):

Bit of an old question, but I stumbled across this answer on Google and thought this could be beneficial to someone.

The values set in the admin section don't work for me - I think the theme I'm currently using is overriding it. For those of you who want/need to make this change via local.xml instead, here's a way of doing it.

Looking at catalog.xml it might seem reasonable to nest setDefaultGridPerPage under product_list_toolbar_pager, that's what I thought too, but that is a self-closing tag and I didn't spot that. What you want to do is nest it under product_list_toolbar instead.

```
<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="product_list_toolbar">
        <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage">
            <limit>15</limit>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>

<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="product_list_toolbar">
        <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage">
            <limit>15</limit>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

This solved the problem for me, at the very least. Your proverbial mileage may vary.

Comment: If you don't know where you can find catalog.xml: `app/design/frontend/default/your_template/layout/catalog.xml`. Then clear the cache. This worked for me as well. I suppose it depends on the template you use.

Answer (score 1):

```
<five_column_grid>
    <reference name="product_list">
        <action method="setColumnCount">
            <count>5</count>
        </action>
    </reference>
</five_column_grid>

<catalog_category_default>
    <update handle="five_column_grid" />
</catalog_category_default>

<catalog_category_layered>
    <update handle="five_column_grid" />
</catalog_category_layered>
```

It should automatically adjust the pager for you.

Have fun :)

Comment: Commenting my answer; obviously set value for 'count' to whatever number you are after.

Comment: Hm, I'm afraid that doesn't change anything. I was already using `<action method="setColumnCount"><columns>5</columns></action>` in catalog_category_default and catalog_category_layered to change the column count. The problem is that I am still getting the default 9 items per page.