# Magento set mode to list in catalog search

Tags: magento

I need to display the List of my products in List Mode by default in my search catalog results. Any ideas how can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can set it from admin menu

Go to : **System -> Configuration -> left side Catalog -> Click on frontend tab**

there are set of drop down on this tab set List Mode to **`List(default)/Grid`**

And check in front end.

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: Thanks but I need the List Mode by default ONLY in my catalog search results

Comment: @pochimen,welcome,it would be glad if you will vote up.if my answer is little helpful to you.

Comment: @pochimen: *liyakat* had given the answer correctly. there's an option **`List(Default)/Grid`** which will show list mode by default. So what's the problem you have?

Answer (score 0):

If you want List Mode layout only for catalog search, then you have to copy and create new list.phtml file as listsearch.phtml and need to update catalogsearch.xml file to point listsearch.phtml

Hope this can help you!

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunatlely I get the following response: Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in  /public_html/web/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/listsearch.phtml on line 49

Comment: Just solve it! This is the correct answer. Just modified the line  <?php if($this->getMode()!='grid'): ?> to  <?php if($this->getMode()!='list'): ?>

Comment: Good :) If you feel, this is correct... then mark as correct. So that other user can get correct answer at once.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

```
  <reference name="product_list_toolbar">
   <action method="setData"><data>_current_grid_mode</data><mode>list</mode></action>
  </reference>
```

Ref: [Change Product List Mode Through Layout Update](http://rajeev-k-tomy.blogspot.it/2014/09/change-product-list-mode-through-layout.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by layouts, just edit catalogsearch.xml and add

```
<action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>30</limit></action>
```

to product_list_toolbar reference

```
<reference name="product_list_toolbar">
```

Comment: Nothing happens, are you sure this gets the default view to LIST?

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316537/how-can-i-change-magentos-default-grid-per-page-in-my-local-xml it should work

Comment: @kuba_ceg: it just change the default limit of products per page to *30* in **Grid** mode. Its not the answer what the user asking.